# RJS not updating html table elements

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a `link_to_remote` function that updates columns in a table.  However, it does not properly update the cell or its properties.

For example:

Here is the element I am updating:

```
 <div id= "calendar_div_<%= i%>_<%=j%>" style = "display :inline;"><td class="checkedout">X</td></div>
```

Using this call:

```
  <%= link_to_remote 'Current Week', :url => { :action => :current_week } %>
```

Calls:

```
render :update do |page|

                    page["Week_div"].replace_html session[:next_week].to_s

                    for i in 0..23 do
                            for j in 0..6 do
                                    page["calendar_div_"+i.to_s+"_"+j.to_s].replace_html '<td class="available">Available</td>'
                            end
                    end
```

However, it never updates the `<td>` tag properly.  The element never updates the text properly nor does it color code the element (`td.available` is defined to have a background color of green).

Comment: Have you used Firebug to see what JavaScript is being returned from the server? If so could you post it here?

Comment: Sure:

$("calendar_div_0_0").update("<th class=\"available\">Available</th>");
$("calendar_div_0_1").update("<td class=\"available\">Available</td>");
$("calendar_div_0_2").update("<td class=\"available\">Available</td>");
$("calendar_div_0_3").update("<td class=\"available\">Available</td>");
$("calendar_div_0_4").update("<td class=\"available\">Available</td>");
$("calendar_div_0_5").update("<td class=\"available\">Available</td>");

This is repeated till calendar_div_23_6.  I'm not seeing any errors, the post doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, ryanb was mostly correct.  You can't do it using `<div><td>` tag order.  Rather you need to use an id for the `<td>` tag.

However, this was STILL not correctly updating the cell to overwrite the color; the previous background was still appearing, with the new overriding the area where they overlapped.  To properly replace the entire element use the following syntax instead:

```
 $("calendar_div_0_1").replace("<td class=\"available\">Available</td>");
```

Rather than using update, use **replace**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Prototype included in your application.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

Also if you don't have valid HTML sometimes prototype will have trouble traversing the DOM. Try [validating the page](http://validator.w3.org/), specifically fixing any tags which don't have a closing one.

Beyond that you can try to isolate the problem by experimenting. Try this for example.

```
<div id="calendar_div_0_1"><td class="checkedout">X</td></div>
<%= link_to_function "update", "$('calendar_div_0_1').update('<td class=\"available\">Available</td>');" %>
```

That works for me.

Comment: <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> <style sheet defined here> <table> <th> testing </th> <tr> <div id="calendar_div_0_2"> I'ma a test</div> <tr> <div id="calendar_div_0_1"><td class="checkedout">X</td></div> </table> <br> <%= link_to_function "update", "$('calendar_div_0_1').update('<td class=\"available\">Available</td>');" %> <br> <%= link_to_function "update 2", "$('calendar_div_0_2').update('<td class=\"available\">Available</td>');" %>

Comment: Update 2 works, yet update does not.

However, both updates don't change the color of the <td> tag

Comment: This will replace the text AND highlight the word 'Availalble' in green:

    <td class="checkedout"><div id="calendar_div_0_2"> I'ma a test</div></td>

However, there is a red box surrounding the word 'Available', where the `<td class="checkedout">` tag is not totally replaced by:

    `<%= link_to_function "update 2", $('calendar_div_0_2').update('<td class=\"available\">Available</td>');" %>`.

Comment: Further, the 'update' link places the word 'Available' above the table, it does NOT replace the text.  It also does not have the colored background.

Comment: It is very likely the problem has to do with `<div>` being embedded in the middle of a table. This is invalid and likely messing up DOM traversing/replacing. I highly recommend validating the HTML and removing the divs. Place the `id` attribute in the `td` tag instead: <td class="checkedout" id="calendar_div_0_1 ">X</td>

Comment: I'll try that.

I can't validate the code as it is hosted internally.

Comment: You can validate by copy & pasting the source: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input. Or use something like the Web Developer Toolbar addon in FireFox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60